# Where is the Google Tasks folder on Android?

Tags: data-recovery, 9.0-pie, google-tasks

According to this [website](https://g4rud4.gitlab.io/2021/Google-Tasks-Android-Forensics-analysis/), it's

/data/data/com.google.android.apps.tasks/.

On my phone, there's no such folder anywhere. In fact, there's no /data/data anywhere. I do have the Tasks app installed. My Android version is 9, my phone is a Samsung Galaxy J5.

I am hoping that I can recover an older version of Tasks' database, because something very important was somehow deleted, that's why I am looking for the folder. Anyone knows where it is?

Comment: I thought as much. Not going to root the phone. Any way I can access the folder if the phone is plugged in into a Windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/data/data` contains the app-private folders. On devices without root you can not access this folder, neither on the device nor using a connected PC.

But there may be one way to get indirect access to the data:

Google Tasks app seem to have backup enabled, so you could try to get the private app data via adb backup:

```
adb backup com.google.android.apps.tasks
```

If the created file is larger than 1KB the backup may contain the file(s) you want to get access to. You can decrypt the created backup file using this command-line tool: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor

Using adb requires an USB connection to a PC, activated developer options on the phone and inside the developer options  an enabled "Android Debug Bridge" option. On PC side you need adb installed from Android SDK and the adb driver assigned to the correct device manager (assuming you use Windows).

Comment: Unfortunately, the backup returns a 1KB file. Still, the app data takes over 3MB and the cache 311 KB, so I would like to try to extract them and see what's there. I tried adb pull and that doesn't work essentially because the phone is not rooted. I tried to use run-as, but I was told the package is not debuggable. I can't even list the directory contents. Any idea that doesn't involve rooting my phone?

Comment: @Nicola As I wrote adb backup is the only chance to extract app data on an unrooted phone. There is no other way. The security concept of Android does not allow user access to app-private data.